# How to make a request to Node.js server not fail when previewing Angular app on a different device on the same network?

Tags: android, node.js, angular, mobile

Angular front-end is hosted on port 4200. Express.js back-end is hosted on port 4000. Both are hosted on my desktop computer.

Now I am on my mobile Android phone and navigate to 192.168.1.X:4200 to view the Angular app. The Angular app loads and works but with no data loaded from the Express.js server. From my desktop computer, the request to the Express.js server works fine and the Angular app in the browser displays proper data. Accessing 192.168.1.X:4000 (API for the data) on both devices' browser returns the expected JSON.

I connected my phone to my desktop computer via USB to debug. Here is the error in Chrome DevTools Console:

`GET http://localhost:4000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

and

```
ERROR 
  HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:4000/", ok: false, …}
    error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
    headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
    message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4000/: 0 Unknown Error"
    name: "HttpErrorResponse"
    ok: false
    status: 0
    statusText: "Unknown Error"
    url: "http://localhost:4000/"
    __proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Network tab in Chrome DevTools...

Network:

```
Name: localhost
Status: (failed)
Type: xhr
Initiator: zone-evergreen.js:2952
```

Network Headers:

```
General
  Request URL: http://localhost:4000/
  Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Request Headers
  Provisional headers are shown
  Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
  Origin: http://192.168.1.2:4200
  Referer: http://192.168.1.2:4200/
  Save-Data: on
  Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SM-G965W) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.92 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Express.js code:

```
const express = require('express'),
      cors = require('cors');

const app = new express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.json({data: "a lot of data"});
});


app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Back-end listening on port: 4000')
});
```

So, the request to the Express.js server is failing when accessing the Angular app through my phone but not through my desktop computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you are making requests from Angular code to Express server you are using `localhost` as ip address.
This will work on your PC as the Express.js app is served on your local PC. But when the angular application runs on mobile it will not be able to access your express server.
What you can do is that instead of making requests to `localhost` use the ip address `192.168.1.X:4000`. This way even when viewing angular on the mobile browser the request will reach the express server.
Hope that helps !

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Angular code `this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/')` needed to be changed to `this.http.get('http://192.168.1.X:4000/')`. Thanks for the extra pair of eyes (although I didn't post my Angular code).

Answer (score 0):

Update

`app.listen(4000, 193.168.1.X, () => {
  console.log('Back-end listening on port: 4000')
});`

Now call http request from angular using Ip address (192.168.1.X) instead of localhost